# Java: List listener for passed reference needed?

Tags: java

I want to pass a reference of a dynamic list basically. in Class2 the getTheList method should keep getting the new list even when the orginal list changes. Should I add a listener or I have to change my design in a better way to do this?

```
class1{
    public class1(){
       List orginalList=getOrginalList();
       Class2 c2=new Class2(orginalList);
    }

    public List getOrginalList(){ 
          //here read and return the updated orginal
         //List from a web service
    }           
}

class2{
    List myList;
    public class2(List realList){
        myList=realList;
    }
    private int getTheList(){
        //when I call this method I want to get the updated list
        return  myList.size();
    }    
}
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish what you want, assuming that what you want is to pass a reference and not copy the list. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I've answered it as best I can, but please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions as to how to improve it.

Comment: Please create a short http://SSCCE.org, as your example has flaws in it (i.e trying to call a private instance method without a class reference, and the methods modifier is private?! public is what is should be) and the question is not clear.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer..

Comment: You will need to show us the code in `getOriginalList()`

Answer (score 0):

From your comment...

```
//something here later changes the orginal list but In class2 
//I still keep getting the old list!
```

... it looks like you expect there to be two list objects. There aren't. There's just one list, which you have two references to. If you want to make a copy of the list, you'll need to do that explicitly. The assignment operator *never* creates a copy of an object. It just copies the value of one expression to a variable. The value of that expression is *always* either a reference or a primitive value - *never* an object.

Comment: My interpretation was that the OP wanted to pass the reference, and somehow managed to get a copy instead.

Comment: i never had a chance that, my questions got answered by Jon Skeet. A genious with multi programming language knowledge.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank you, I updated the question. I dont want a copy of my list

Comment: @Keppil yes I want to pass referance